# The EventLogWebEventProvider provider failed to log an event with the error code 0x80070057

Tags: asp.net, event-log

I am writing WebEvent in my asp.net Application and it is working fine in both my development and production region.However, When I analyze Event Logs in production server for past couple of months.I see below event

```
 The following exception was thrown by the web event provider 'EventLogProvider' in   the application '/(MyApplicationName)' (in an application lifetime a maximum of one exception will be logged per provider instance):

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The EventLogWebEventProvider provider failed to log an event with the error code 0x80070057.

at System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider.ProcessEvent(WebBaseEvent eventRaised)

at System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent.RaiseInternal(WebBaseEvent eventRaised, ArrayList firingRuleInfos, Int32 index0, Int32 index1)
```

Although Occurrence is very low, still I am curious to understand why this is happening.I tried to do some research and found below link
http://forums.iis.net/t/1201176.aspx?IIS+Keep+hanging

According to this link, I may be passing some invalid argument while writing event log.
But I double checked my EventLog.WriteEntry method and I am using it in my application only in couple of places and moreover, I am passing static string message. If argument is invalid then it should occur every time I try to write event.

Can anyone please help me understanding possible cause for this event.is there any known issue when working with EvenLog?

Comment: i also facing this issue , have any solution please?????

Comment: No, still do not know why this happens.......

Answer (score 1):

Check your code you may be trying to perform an invalid operation.

In my case i was writing a file to C Drive after changing Location to D Drive Problem Resolved

Comment: Well I do not have code base anymore....This issue was occurring long time back....However, This is Event Log which we were writing are the oneswhich you see in Event Viewer...not the events which you write in log files....Plus it was definitely not security issues because the error was sporadic...